# Shell Script - Iterate through each line in text file and rename HDFS file

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs

I have a text file in HDFS which would have records like below. The number of lines in file may vary every time.
hdfs://myfile.txt

```
file_name_1
file_name_2
file_name_3
```

I have the below hdfs directory and file structure like below.

```
hdfs://myfolder/
hdfs://myfolder/file1.csv
hdfs://myfolder/file2.csv
hdfs://myfolder/file3.csv
```

Using shell script I am able to count the number of files in HDFS directory and number of lines available in my HDFS text file. Only if the count matches between the number of files in directory and number of records in my text file, I am going to proceed further with the process.

Now, i am trying to rename hdfs://myfolder/file1.csv to hdfs://myfolder/file_name_1.csv using the first record from my text file.
Second file should be renamed to hdfs://myfolder/file_name_2.csv and third file to hdfs://myfolder/file_name_3.csv

I have difficulty in looping through both the text file and also the files in HDFS directory.
Is there an optimal way to achieve this using shell script.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "rename". If you just need the first file with each line prepended with `hdfs://myfolder/` and suffixed with .csv then that's easy: `sed -e 's,\(.*\),hdfs://myfolder/\1.csv,' < myfile.txt`.

Comment: I already have the files in hdfs with different names. I have to rename it. Will be using hdfs dfs -mv to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly from HDFS, you'd need to stream the file contents, then issue individual move commands.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

COUNTER = 0
for file in $(hdfs dfs -cat file.txt)
do 
  NAME = $(sed $file ...)  # replace text, as needed. TODO: extract the extension
  hdfs dfs -mv file "$NAME_${COUNTER}.csv"  # 'csv' for example - make sure the extension isn't duplicated!!
  COUNTER = $((COUNTER + 1)
done
```